# Different Browser and OS render different the fonts is causing absolute divs to look differently

Tags: html

I'm working on a web site which content and positioning of the elements loads from database, each element (text, form, images) loads inside a div with absolute positioning, using the top attribute of the div for vertical psition. it works fine most of the time and the elements render and look how they suppose to. How ever when i load large amount of text on a div element the space between the content and the div changes in different OS, or browser versions, im not sure which but i think its on different os because firefox 3.6.17 look different on windos xp and mac os.

Im pretty sure its because the fonts are reendered different in different browser which cause this inconsistence.

Problem comes when i want to show another element below the first content, the space between them changes heavily, causing that in some OS/Browser the second element looks way bellow the content, and so some people don´t look at this second element because they think the page is over.

However the div them self are well positioned
[image: Windowss IE8]
[image: Macos Safari]

I was looking into Google WebFont Loader, but i think this solution only focus in the loading process of a font and uses Javascript to make them behave the same, but not look the same. It still needs some tests, but it occurred to me that the only way to fix this is with javascript, and i was wondering if some one have encounter a similar problem, or if you have a suggestion, cause it would be of great use for us! thank you!

Comment: Certainly not OS-related. Screen resolution is the culprit, and the fact that you are probably not using *clean* CSS.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make to user see that there is more content would be to use tabbed browsing.

Comment: Dont really understand how tabbed browsing is related, doesn't it reffers to the tabs in the browsers ?

Comment: no it doesnt refer to a tab in a browser. It refers to tab within the html content. http://www.dhtmlkitchen.com/scripts/tabs/Tabs/demo/dual.html

Comment: in this case the UI would suite much if you have the content in each tab restricted - not to exceed that page.